# How to re-instantiate a class with static methods?

Tags: swift, class, static

I've a class to manage my SQLite database, so I've a static variable to store my path of database.

```
class SQLite {

    static let fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent(SQLiteManager.databaseName())
    .
    .
    . // static methods...
    static func readById<T: ObjectInit>(tabela: String, id: Int, typeClass: T.Type) -> T { ... }
}
```

But when I change the user logged I need re-instantiate this class without restart app, so I do this?

Comment: Do you only need to update/recalculate the value of `fileUrl`?

Comment: yes..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make `fileUrl` mutable and when the user logs out, then in again, you can update `fileUrl` with its new value.

```
static var fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent(SQLiteManager.databaseName())

func login(){
    //Do all login related tasks
    ...
    // After the user is logged in and SQLiteManager.databaseName() is updated
    SQLite.fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent(SQLiteManager.databaseName())
}
```

You could also make `fileUrl` a computed property, but if you actually only need to update it after the user logged out and then in again and use `fileUrl` much more often than the user switching, it would be an overkill to recalculate `fileUrl` every time you access it.

Another possibility would be to recalculate `fileUrl` from `SQLiteManager.databaseName()` assuming that function is a custom function that you can modify and not a method from a 3rd party library.